# Flash not readable in html?

Tags: flash, flash-cs6

I have the stupidest problem there could be in flash with a client. they asked for a banner, and  I made one in cs6. they called back and said when we insert it in the html code and upload it, the flash doesn'y show and the "smart guy" from their it told me it's because it's made in the latest version and needs to b converted to an old. I saved as an cs5 project but they said it's still the same. I just want to know, is there any way to convert a cs6 file to flas 8 file, or does it mater in what version is it made for the html code?

Comment: you should save it using older flash player version?

Comment: I saved it as cs5 file, but how do I save it for older flash players?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saving your fla as CS5 wont help. You have to change the target version of flash.

Go to

```
File -> Publish Settings -> Flash -> Change Player to Flash PLayer 8
```

Publish & pass them the SWF. Doesn't matter which Flash IDE you use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just saved it for flash player 8, if they got anything older then they need to consult stone age flashers :)

Comment: I used to do banners a lot earlier in the year... this is exactly the problem. You should be fine with up to flash player 10.1, for yahoo APT and Google AdWords. 10.2 is what the default is and is the hiccup :). Also, you can access a dropbox for this option in the properties panel of Flash when you don't have an object selected.